# Bootstrap grid: vertical placement of multiple divs in a row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In a Bootstrap `.row`, I have an arbitrary number of divs (with classes `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3`) which each have their own height.

The result (on a large screen) is like this picture (`.row` in red, `.col`s in black):

[image: bad grid]

I would like every div to be as high as it can, right below the div above it, as in the picture below. Is that possible with Bootstrap, without having to manually sort my divs into columns?

[image: good grid]

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"> [stuff] </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"> [stuff] </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"> [stuff] </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: OK, editing my question but it's just one row with a lot of divs.

Comment: This is called a Masonry layout. There is no current pure CSS way to achieve this and you'd have to use JavaScript to do it.

Comment: @Aziz Is right use [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Oh :( but thanks for your answer, I'll look that up.

Answer (score 0):

Bill Reinhardt created a nice layout for you to start from.

This should help you:
https://codepen.io/billreinhardt/pen/ZGVNJL

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Masonry CSS with Bootstrap</h1>
    <div class="row">
<div class="item">
  <div class="well"> 
    1 blah blah blah
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="well"> 
    2 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="well"> 
    3 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah h
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="well">
    blah blah blah blah 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="well"> 
      blah blah blah. The container inside the item must be position:relative
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="well"> 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="well">
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah h
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="well"> 
    blah blah blah blah
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="well"> 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="well"> 
      blah blah blah. The container inside the item must be position:relative
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
 -moz-column-width: 18em;
 -webkit-column-width: 18em;
 -moz-column-gap: 1em;
 -webkit-column-gap:1em; 

}

.item {
 display: inline-block;
 padding:  .25rem;
 width:  100%; 
}

.well {
 position:relative;
 display: block;
}
```